# Bind parameters must be array Error in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with Nodejs/express "API" and i am trying to use "paramerized query" but i am getting following error in my console

```
Bind parameters must be array if namedPlaceholders parameter is not enabled
```

Here is my controller

```
const result= await User.addServiceDetail(UserId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName); //passing data to model
```

Here is my model file,Where i am wrong ?

```
static async addServiceDetail(UserId,serviceId,genderTypeId,price,serviceName)
    {
const sql = await pool.execute(`SELECT id from hc_servicesdetail WHERE UserId= ? AND  serviceId = ? AND genderTypeId='genderTypeId'`,[UserId, serviceId])
console.log(sql);
}
```

Here is my "default.js" (connection file)

```
module.exports = {
    PORT: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    DB_HOST: process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost',
    DB_PORT: process.env.DB_PORT || '',
    DB_USERNAME: process.env.DB_USERNAME || 'root',
    DB_USERNAME_PASSWORD: process.env.DB_USERNAME_PASSWORD || '',
    DB_NAME: process.env.DB_NAME || 'api',
};
```

Comment: can you share your `mysql.createConnection` details?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Updated my question ,kindly check and update your answer please

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added `namedPlaceholders: true` in your Mysql connection code.

For Ex:

```
const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'my_database',
  namedPlaceholders: true,
});
```

Comment: I updated my question kindly check and let me know where i am wrong ?

Comment: You need to add `namedPlaceholders: true` to your DB connection file.